# How to make a C "library" that can be reused in different code bases?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I am working on a project for school and I think we can use the same code in two separate projects. The code essentially connects to a socket running on the host machine that is running a simulator that provides traffic data (x, y positions). These positions are parsed into a struct:

```
struct Vehicle{
    Double x;
    Double y;
    int id;
    int type;
}
```

A list of these structs would be returned to the program that instantiated the library. So I would like to take this code that I have to parse the data and have a common method that can pass the structs back to the caller after every event (every 1ms roughly). How would I go about doing this?

Update:

The part that is unclear to me is having the library take data every `x` seconds and then have it pass that data to another file that updates accordingly. So if `fileA` is the code that draws the positions and `fileB` handles the parsing of the data into the structs, how would I update the canvas in methods in `fileA` by passing the data back from `fileB` (as opposed to calling some method in fileB to get the data).

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you? You compile the code into a shared library and define the api (public functions and structures) in a header file, which you include in source files that use functions from your shared library.

Comment: Create a .c file with a set of functions to do the work, and a corresponding .h file with the prototypes of the functions along with any necessary `struct` definitions.

Comment: posted an update at the end of the post @Ctx

Comment: @Citut This has less to do with separate source files and more to do with multithreading and synchronization.

Comment: That syntax isn't C.

Comment: The caller has to ask for the data.

Answer (score 1):

> how would I update the canvas in methods in fileA by passing the data
>   back from fileB (as opposed to calling some method in fileB to get the
>   data).

Each time the data is ready in fileB, the code in fileB needs to call a method in fileA and pass the data into fileA using the called method.

The fileA methods that is called can be hard coded ( always the same ) or at startup the code in fileA can call a fileB method, passing the function that should be called by fileB whenever the data is ready - which is called a "registering a callback"

I am unsure how you would do that in C ( many years since I used that language ).  In C++ it is quite standard, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>         // std::this_thread::sleep_for
#include <chrono>         // std::chrono::seconds

using namespace std;

class B;

class A
{
public:

    // function that should be called when data is ready
    void Callback();

    void Register( B& theB );
};

class B
{
public:
    void RegisterCallback( function<void(void)> f );

    // method that runs whenever new data is ready
    void SendDataToA();

    function<void(void)> myCallback;
};

void A::Register( B& theB )
{
    theB.RegisterCallback( [this]()
    {
        Callback();
    } );
}

void A::Callback()
{
    // B has sent some data
    cout << "A::Callback\n";
}

void B::RegisterCallback( function<void(void)> f )
{
    myCallback = f;
}

void B::SendDataToA()
{
    while( 1 ) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));

        // data is ready, send it to A
        myCallback();
    }
}

int main()
{
    A theA;
    B theB;

    // register A's callback with B
    theA.Register( theB );

    // run B's data pump
    theB.SendDataToA();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm familiar with callbacks, but I'm not sure how to use them in C. Is it similar to Objective-C/Swift/higher level languages?

Comment: Suggest you use C++.  Complex stuff like this is much easier.